# How to add attachments to outlook using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, outlook

I am trying to open outlook from the MFC code that will send the mail with attachments. However I am not able add attachments as i don't know what method to use and even when the mail is sent, the outlook is not opening and the mail is sent directly.

I have used the following code:

```
void COutlookDlgDlg::OnBnClickedOpenoutlook()
{
    CApplication olApp;
    COleException e;
    if (!olApp.CreateDispatch(_T("Outlook.Application"), &e)) {
        CString strErr;
        strErr.Format(_T("CreateDispatch() failed w/error 0x%08lx"), e.m_sc);
        AfxMessageBox(strErr, MB_SETFOREGROUND);
        return;
    }

    CNameSpace olNs(olApp.GetNamespace(_T("MAPI")));
    COleVariant covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
    olNs.Logon(covOptional, covOptional, covOptional, covOptional);

    CMailItem olMailItem(olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem));
    olMailItem.put_To(_T("xyz@abc.com"));
    olMailItem.put_Subject(_T("xyz..."));
    olMailItem.put_Body(_T("Hi mnc,\n\n")
                        _T("\tMail for testing!\n\n"));
    olMailItem.Send();

    olNs.Logoff();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model is common for all kind of applications and programming languages.

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Attachments class creates a new attachment in the Attachments collection (see the Attachments property of the MailItem class).

If you need to display the mail item before sending you may use the [Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861853(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class.

Finally, you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To Automate Outlook Using Visual C++/MFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220600)
- [How to automate Outlook 2010 by using C++ in Visual Studio 2010 together with MFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2575036)

Comment: I created an object of Attachments: Attachments att;                                        When I use att.Add I get an error that object of abstract class type is not allowed. @Eugene Astafiev

Comment: You need to use the object which you get from the Attachments property: `mail.Attachments.Add`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to add attachment now. I have one last question.      If I want to attach multiple files then do I need to mention that again and again in the code? @Eugene Astafiev

Comment: Yes, you need to call the `Add` method multiple times.